# Свой Id для JoinTable в Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть две сущности: **User и Role**, - они имеют отношение многие ко многим. Соответственно, есть три таблицы: **users, roles, user_roles**. Проблема в том, что в **user_roles** есть собственный id, который Hibernate никак не хочет генерировать, когда присваивает новую роль для юзера 
(выбрасывается исключение: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint) Этот id я удалить не могу, т к база не моя (тестовое задание). Подскажите, как можно сказать хибернейту генерировать айдишник?

Comment: Покажите схему БД.

Comment: Схему базы прикрепил к описанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку вам (по непонятным причинам) нужен surrogate key в таблице, которая у вас служит как ассоциация между `user` и `role`, то необходимо создать еще одну сущность. Работать с этой сущностью можно как отдельно, так через сущности `User` и `Role`. Честно говоря, первый вариант мне кажется проще.

Вот тут я слепил [пример проекта на Github](https://github.com/mxbyrd/ruSO_answers/tree/master/hibernate-m2m-533134), надеюсь разберетесь. Учтите только, что использовалась встраиваемая БД и автогенерация схемы. В Posgtre для генерации ID через JPA, вроде как, надо явно указывать sequence, иначе сам не находит, и аннотацию `@ForeignKey` можно опустить - это чтобы Hibernate `hbm2ddl.auto` не генерировал foreign key там где его не просят.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ForeignKey(name = "none")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserRole> userRoles;

    // ...

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( UserRole userRole : userRoles ) {
            roles.add(userRole.getRole());
        }
        return roles;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    @ForeignKey(name = "none")
    private List<UserRole> userRoles;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private UserRoleKey key;

    @ManyToOne
    @ForeignKey(name = "none")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @ForeignKey(name = "none")
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Role role;

    // ...
}

@Embeddable
public class UserRoleKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Long roleID;

    // ...
}
```

Вывод `hbm2ddl.auto`:

```
create table roles (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table user_role (id bigint generated by default as identity, role_id bigint, user_id bigint, primary key (id))
create table users (id bigint generated by default as identity, login varchar(255), name varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

Comment: Спасибо, я в итоге примерно так и сделал

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать что-то такое, если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="UserRoles",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
```